# Rally: StandardCardRenderer Card Styles

Tags: javascript, rally

What are all the card styles for the StandardCardRenderer?  The App SDK only lists card styles for the BasicCardRendered which includes:

.cardboard .card: Style given to each card element 
.cardboard .cardHeader: Style given to each card header element 
.cardboard .cardOwner: Style given to the owner image element in the card header 
.cardboard .cardOwnerName: Style given to the owner name element in the card header 
.cardboard .cardContent: Style given to the card content element 
.cardboard .defect .cardHeader, .cardboard .defectsuite .cardHeader, .cardboard .hierarchicalrequirement .cardHeader, .cardboard .task .cardHeader: Additional styles given to card header elements based on item type.

I suspect the StandardCardRenderer has more card styles.  For instance, the StandardCardRenderer includes a Ready to Pull button and a Blocked button.  I want to hide the Ready to Pull button since we don't use it in my group.  If there is a card style for it like there is for .cardboard .cardOwner, then I could add display:none; to the CSS style section kinda like this:

```
 .cardboard .cardReadyToPull {
    display:none;
  }
```

I would also like to make some other modifications that I could probably control with styles, but I would need to know the card styles to do this.  I opened a ticket with Rally and they incorrectly told me that I can't use card styles to hide objects even though their [App SDK has an example of it](http://www.rallydev.com/help/card-board).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tried to document most of the card styles but the menu styles apparently were never documented fully.  You should be able to do this with CSS.  If you are using Chrome or Firefox use developer tools or Firebug to inspect the html in the menu to find the CSS classes applied.  In this case the following should work for you:

```
.cardboard .cardMenu .readyIndicator {
    display: none;
}
```

Or, if your group has its own workspace you could remove the 'Ready' field from stories and defects- this would also prevent the ready button from being displayed.